# How to access a structured array of unsized type

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

First, I customize a data structure:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[10];
    void* fp;
} test;
```

I created this data structure during the IR phase.

```
static StructType* Test_Type = llvm::StructType::create(C,"test");
```

Also, I create a structured array:

```
test my_test[10];
test* my_test_pointer = my_test;
```

Finally, I tried to access its elements through getelementptr and got the following error:

> GEP into unsized type!
>
> %1 = getelementptr %test, %test* %0, i32 0

What is the cause of this unsized Type?  How do I resolve this error?
Any answer would be of great help to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Functions, labels, metadata, token and void types do not have sizes, nor do array/struct/vector aggregates formed out of them.

I suggest you call `Test_Type->dump()` and take a look at what your type really is.